# ESP32 HTTP Update and x-MD5 header

Tags: esp32, ota

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/HTTPUpdate

I found out that this library can read x-MD5 header but looks like it's going through with the update no matter what MD5 I set. I thought it's for verifying the update, I do md5sum of my bin file on the server and then ESP32 checks the hash of downloaded bin to confirm the file wasn't corrupted during download. Am I wrong here? What's the purpose of this x-MD5 header if not for this?

If it has another purpose, how do I make sure that the bin with the update wasn't corrupted during download so I don't brick ESP32?

Comment: there is in Update.cpp a condition `if(strlen(expected_md5) != 32)`